# how to expose authStateChanges() stream through the state property in a class that extends notifier

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to learn Riverpod so this may be a stupid question but here is what I am struggling with.

I have a AuthService class that extends Notifier. This class works with firebase auth to sign user in and out. I am trying to monitor _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges() event so that I can display correct widget to the user based on if the user is authenticated or not. Here is how my AuthService class looks like:

```
class AuthService extends Notifier<AppUser> {
  AuthService(this._firebaseAuth) {
    // Empty constructor body
  }

  AppUser? _appUserFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    if (null != user) {
      return AppUser(uid: user.uid);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Stream<AppUser?> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((user) {
      return _appUserFromFirebaseUser(user);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that visual studio code is showing me a warning for the Stream<AppUser?> getter saying `"Notifiers should not have public properties/getters. Instead, all their public API should be exposed through the state property."` which tells me I must be doing something wrong the way I am trying to monitor the `_firebaseAuth.authStateChanges()` stream.

Can someone please tell me how do I do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add a constructor for classes that extend `Notifier`.  The protocol for constructing a notifier is to call the zero-arg constructor (the default) and then call `build()`.  You don't appear to have a `build()` and should have gotten a lint on that. That build is free to use globals or other providers to provide initialization values.

And, the error you're seeing is also correct.  A notifier's public methods should only be to mutate the state, returning `void` or `Future<void>`.  Extraneous methods should be on other classes.

Comment: I do have build method. I just set state to null in that method. I made the changes and initialized _firebaseAuth variable in the build method and removed it from constructor. Also figured out the problem why it was giving me lint warning on that. Fixed that too. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.